# How do I disable mouse scroll wheel under Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, scroll-wheel

In Ubuntu 9.04, I am looking for a way to disable my mouses scroll so that the mouse works like an old fashioned 3-button mouse without the scroll functionality.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file so that the scrolling is ignored. You should be able to find a section similar to this for your mouse:

```
Section "InputDevice"
    [...]
EndSection
```

Change it to the following to ignore scrolling:

```
Section "InputDevice"
    [...]
    Option "HorizScrollDelta" "0"
    Option "VertScrollDelta" "0"
EndSection
```

This just makes it so scrolling scrolls by zero.

**You may also be able to set this option through the Mouse control panel** by setting the scroll amount to zero.

Comment: This did not work for me in KDE