# How to disable default key action (horizontal scroll wheel) in xbindkeys?

Tags: linux, remapping, key-binding, scroll-wheel, xbindkeys

I'm currently using horizontal scroll wheel (MX Master 3) with xbindkeys (`~/.xbindkeysrc`) to control volume on Pop OS 20.04 (~Ubuntu) but currently it activates horizontal scroll along also, and I don't want that. Is it possible to disable that?

```
"pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ -1200"
  b:6
```

Comment: I have a similar issue, I control virtual desktops with the thumb scroll wheel, and it conflicts with the horizontal scroll that is bound to it by default.

Comment: @Michael Does this work for you? https://superuser.com/questions/52389/how-do-i-disable-mouse-scroll-wheel-under-ubuntu?rq=1

Comment: Almost, but not quite. When I used `Option "HorizontalScrolling" 0`, it seemed to disable the thumb wheel altogether, which is not what I want. Did you figure it out?